# Stop executing sequelize default Delete on moleculer service restart

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, moleculer

I am using moleculer micro services and postgres database with modules 'moleculer-db-adapter-sequelize' and 'Sequelize'. Every time i save any code moleculer service gets restarted at that time sequelize runs a DELETE query. How to stop it running that delete query?

Answer (score 0):

As I can't add a comment, I ask this in the answer section.

We will need a bit more informations could you provide some sample of your code?

I suspect that you have a DELETE query in some part of your service lifecycle event.